# ssh: connect to host {IP Address} port 22: Operation timed out

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, vps, ubuntu-server, google-compute-engine

I was setting up a firewall with UFW in Ubuntu server, I skipped the step `sudo ufw allow ssh` and instead run the command `sudo ufw enable`. Rebooted the VPS but now when I try to connect using ssh, I get the following error `ssh: connect to host {IP Address} port 22: Operation timed out`.

I am using Google Cloud Compute Infrastructure and  I'm not understanding details in this article https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror

Is there a way I can rollback?

Comment: This could be longer than expected. Since you have not allowed access to your instance, there's no way you can get in there now. You can do this though: Stop the current instance and make sure that disk is not deleted. Start a new instance with a new boot disk. Add your stopped instance's disk to this new instance. Recover any data. Use the new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can login to your instance using the serial console. After logging in you should run the command: `sudo ufw allow ssh`, for allowing ssh access to your instance.

See [Interacting with the Serial Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) for more information